# jQuery keydown handler receives keydown event when Ctrl is pressed in URL field of IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, keydown

In IE11 there is a strange behavior of firing a keydown event.

Please use the following URL to reproduce:
http://jsfiddle.net/marbug/79dz6ajz/

There is a form with two input fields:

```
<form>
    <input class="usernameField" type="text" ></input><br>
    <input class="passwordField" type="password" ></input><br>
</form>
```

and there are the following handlers (jQuery 1.11.0):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.usernameField').keydown( function(event) {
        console.log('usernameField keydown');
    });
    $('.usernameField').keyup( function(event) {
        console.log('usernameField keyup');
    });
    $('.passwordField').keydown( function(event) {
        console.log('passwordField keydown');
    });
    $('.passwordField').keyup( function(event) {
        console.log('passwordField keyup');
    });
});
```

1) Let's reproduce the issue with the username field

- Put focus at username field.
- Then click at browser's URL field.
- Press Ctrl on keyboard.
- The keydown handler of the username field receives an event. I.e. see 'usernameField keydown' in console.

2) Now let's do the same with password field

- Put focus at password field.
- Then click at browser's URL field.
- Press Ctrl on keyboard.
- The keydown handler of the password field receives an event. I.e. see 'passwordField keydown' in console.

Is this a bug of IE11 or jQuery?

P.S. Keyup event (for Ctrl key) is not fired in all of these cases. It's also strange.

Comment: I do not understand you question. You are binded the keyup / keydown to your inputs. So why do you wondering, nothing happens, when non of them is focused? And anyway, you can shorten your code: http://jsfiddle.net/79dz6ajz/16/

Comment: Ok. I've removed 3). And thanks for code enhancement but I would prefer to leave it as is - IMHO current version is more clear.

Comment: Ok, but then, what is your problem? It works for me in IE

Comment: The problem is that event should not be fired when the appropriate field is not focused.

Comment: Now I am totally lost. This is how it should works. You are attaching an event, eg. keydown to an input field. If the focus is not on that input, then why should fired any keydown? Use `$(document).keyDown()` if you want to be always triggered.

Comment: Ok. This is how it should work.Go to http://jsfiddle.net/marbug/79dz6ajz/ Click at the username input (focus is set). Then click at the browser's URL field (where http://jsfiddle.net/marbug/79dz6ajz/ is present). Focus is at browser's URL field - username field has lost focus now. Press Ctrl. Keydown event should not be fired for username field because focus is not at the username field now.

Comment: Yes, I've checked your fiddle before, and everything is works fine. You meen, it works on jsfiddle, but not on your machine, or what? I focus on pw and get `passwordField keydown` and `passwordField keyup` then go to userField and `userField keydown` and `userField keyup`. That is right, this is in IE11, works great. This is what your script should do.

Comment: The bug is present not only on jsfiddle. I use jsfiddle just to simplify a bug reproducing. I do not get why you think that everything works fine. If field is not focused then it should not receive keydown event when keyboard button is pressed.

Comment: Hm, not sure, so you talking about CTRL key? That is works too for me.

Comment: @lolka_bolka The problem is, that when the addressbar has the focus, the keydown event of password and username fields is fired, if you press CTRL on addressbar.

Comment: Now I've got it. Strange, and what is strange also that only the keydown. If you add one more input, then that keydown will fired. So it seems, always the last fired. Maybe you should ask this on a microsoft forum.

Answer (score 0):

Good ideas usually come later.

It's the issue of IE11.

The issue can be also reproduced without jQuery:

```
<script>
    function keyIsDownOnUsername(event) {
        console.log('keyIsDown on username');
    }
    function keyIsUpOnUsername(event) {
        console.log('keyIsUp on username');
    }
    function keyIsDownOnPassword(event) {
        console.log('keyIsDown on password');
    }
    function keyIsUpOnPassword(event) {
        console.log('keyIsUp on password');
    }
</script>
<form>
    <input onkeydown="keyIsDownOnUsername(event)" onkeyup="keyIsUpOnUsername(event)" type="text" ></input><br>
    <input onkeydown="keyIsDownOnPassword(event)" onkeyup="keyIsUpOnPassword(event)" type="password" ></input><br>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/marbug/42hnaneo/

Question has been addressed to Microsoft:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6a065a6d-f378-4a32-8497-3f694bf82152/keydown-handler-receives-keydown-event-when-ctrl-is-pressed-in-url-field-of-ie11?forum=ieitprocurrentver